# Docker nodejs set timezone

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have nodejs container (created from node:14-alpine) running within docker-compose with NestJs application running in it. The problem is that I cannot set different timezone for nodejs (it is always UTC). Timezone on my VPS and within the container is Europe/Kiev. But whenever I'm running `new Date()` it is returning time in UTC. I tried to set in via ENV variable, but it doesnt work. I have the same problem on Windows local machine. Enviromnent variables works fine, cause I have my DB credentials there. But timezone variable just has no effect.

Here's my .env file

```
DB_HOST=host
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=pass
TZ=Europe/Kiev
```

Comment: Javascript `Date` objects are always UTC. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a fluxble time management like moment.js/ Luxon js to generate date depend to the client browser or you can add specific location .

- Moment JS website: [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) .
- Luxon js website: [luxon js](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) .

Example to generate date for specific location:

```js
DateTime.now().setZone('**America/New_York**').minus({ weeks: 1 }).endOf('day').toISO();
```

Notice: